# double-encryption --- http/s to an https proxy

Tags: https, http-proxy

There are several different approaches to security for web proxying:

- No security. Client connects to proxy with HTTP, makes GET request (proxy probably uses HTTP to reach destination).
- HTTPS connection to proxy, then GET request. Encryption only between proxy and client.
- HTTP to proxy, CONNECT tunnel to destination (host named in clear-text), letting client HTTPS to destination. Security-wise, seems equivalent to direct HTTPS.
- HTTPS to proxy, CONNECT tunnel to destination, then HTTPS to destination. (E.g., so that not even the destination host name metadata can be eavesdropped on an untrusted local network like public wifi.)

My question is about the final case. Is there any standard or RFC that describes it?

Does/must the content get double-encrypted or not? That is, on the client side, should the proxy simply forward the raw data stream (without manipulation) after the CONNECT is established, or should it still continue applying its (now-redundant) secure wrapper?